# Problem with tstring typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, typedef, tchar

I am having a problem with trying to typedef myself a nice handy tstring (see below)

```
#ifndef _NISAMPLECLIENT_H_
#define _NISAMPLECLIENT_H_

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; // ERROR here (1)

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define CommandLineToArgv CommandLineToArgvW
#else
#define CommandLineToArgv CommandLineToArgvA
#endif

typedef basic_string<TCHAR> tstring; // ERROR HERE (2)
```

I get a compiler error when trying to compile this. The error at "ERROR here (1)" is :

> Error  3   error C2871: 'std' : a namespace with this name does not exist \nisampleclient\nisampleclientdefs.h 16

If I remove the `using namespace std;`declaration and change ERROR HERE (2) to say `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;`then I get an error:

> Error  3   error C2653: 'std' : is not a class or namespace name   \nisampleclient\nisampleclientdefs.h    23

at that point instead.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the `string` header (`#include <string>`, not string.h ;)).

Also, don't ever use:

```
using namespace ...
```

... in headers unless you want to call down the wrath of your fellow developers ;)

Side-note: in C++ most of the traditional C standard headers have counter-parts without `.h` extension but with a leading `c`. In your case `#include <cstdlib>` would be the better choice, although it depends on the compilers you use whether there is an actual difference.

Comment: I actually did try it the other way first. "using namespace ... " is my bastion of last hope.
Including string.h makes no difference. Thanks though.

Comment: I did not write `string.h`, I wrote `string` ;) ... the `string.h` in a C++ project would normally become `cstring`.

Comment: You are spot on. The problem was in fact that I was using string.h not string. Jebus!

Answer (score 5):

`std::basic_string` class template takes three arguments. So you've to do this:

```
 #include <string> //include this

 typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR> > tstring;
```

Comment: Actually to my knowledge the second template parameter is optional.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: That doesn't seem from the class definition. How can you say that?

Comment: Hard to include code in a comment, but I'll try. Since the STL is standardized I presume you have the same code: `template <
   class CharType,
   class Traits=char_traits<CharType>, 
   class Allocator=allocator<CharType> 
>
class basic_string`
The two parameters with the `=` assign defaults to those template parameters. So unless you want to override these, you're just fine with giving the first one.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: Thanks. I saw that in the forward declaration of basic_string. Didn't see this before.